# Slot Inheritance in Vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm trying to understand how/if I can define some sort of slot inheritance in Vue.js v3.  I have a `Container` class that defines 2 slots: `title` and `items`.  I extend `Container` in my `Grid` class, and I define the `items` slot in there.  When I go to use my `Grid` class, I would like to define the `title` slot.  [Fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuejs-slot-inheritance-6fevw?file=/src/App.vue) for reference.

Container.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <header v-if="showTitle">
      <slot name="title" />
    </header>

    <main v-if="showItems">
      <slot name="items" />
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "MyContainer",
  computed: {
    showTitle() {
      return !!this.$slots.title;
    },
    showItems() {
      return !!this.$slots.items;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Grid.vue

```
<template>
  <MyContainer>
    <template #items>
      <span>Here are my items</span>
    </template>
  </MyContainer>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import MyContainer from "@/components/base/Container";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "MyGrid",
  extends: MyContainer,
  components: { MyContainer },
});
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <MyGrid>
      <!-- How can I pass this along to MyGrid's base class? -->
      <template #title>
        <span>This is my title!</span>
      </template>
    </MyGrid>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyGrid from "@/components/base/Grid";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    MyGrid,
  },
};
</script>
```

The issue is in `App.vue` where I have the comment in the template--I would like to pass along defining the slot in there.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](https://gist.github.com/loilo/73c55ed04917ecf5d682ec70a2a1b8e2), I would have to define a template that essentially passes on any slots defined on the instance.  So in my `Grid.vue` class, I would add this code:

```
<template>
  <MyContainer>
    <template #items>
      <span>Here are my items</span>
    </template>
    <!-- Added this template -->
    <template v-for="(_, name) in $slots" v-slot:[name]="slotData">
      <slot :name="name" v-bind="slotData" />
    </template>
  </MyContainer>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import MyContainer from "@/components/base/Container";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "MyGrid",
  extends: MyContainer,
  components: { MyContainer },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In `Grid` component define the title slot then inside it render its children dynamically using `component` :

```
 <MyContainer>
    <template #title>
      <component v-for="(el, i) in $slots.title()" :is="el" :key="i">
      </component>
    </template>
    <template #items>
      <span>Here are my items</span>
    </template>
  </MyContainer>
</template>
```

**[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuejs-slot-inheritance-forked-kc2ss?file=/src/components/base/Grid.vue)**